# Xamarin.UITest Tests not working only on real Android devices

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.uitest, xamarin-test-cloud

I'm new to XamarinUITest and I am having trouble running it on real devices locally (in preparation for AppCenter Test).

When I run it using an Android emulator, the test runs smoothly, passes and completes.

When I run it on a real device connected to my machine (OnePlus 5T) I get the following issues:

```
      Message: 
System.Exception : Post to endpoint '/ping' failed after 100 retries. No http result received

  Stack Trace: 
AppInitializer.StartApp(Platform platform) line 24
Login.BeforeEachTest() line 25

  Standard Output: 
Full log file: C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\log-2021-11-25_13-54-49-953.txt
Skipping IDE integration as important properties are configured. To force IDE integration, add .PreferIdeSettings() to ConfigureApp.
Android test running Xamarin.UITest version: 3.2.3
Initializing Android app on device 3acaec7 with apk: C:\Users\Steve\source\repos\MyTestApp\MyTestApp.Android\bin\Dev\com.mytestapp.dev-Signed.apk
Skipping local screenshots. Can be enabled with EnableScreenshots() when configuring app.
Signing apk with Xamarin keystore.
```

I have internet permissions on in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

##### AppInitializer

```
public static IApp StartApp(Platform platform)
{
    try
    {
        if (platform == Platform.Android)
            return ConfigureApp.Android.ApkFile(@"C:\Users\Steve\source\repos\MyTestApp\MyTestApp.Android\bin\Dev\com.mytestapp.dev-Signed.apk").StartApp();
        else
            return ConfigureApp.iOS.StartApp();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw(ex);
    }
}
```

I get this same issue if I try upload it to AppCenter. If I run the app when the APK file is already on the device then the test loading indicator keeps spinning forever.

I have tried `.InstalledApp()` instead and also had no luck on real devices. This is v important so I really appreciate everyone chimming in. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? We are suffering from the same one.

Comment: @T.Y.Kucuk this one was an absolute nightmare to fix. but my project is fine now. My solution ended up being creating a brand new project with the most up to date Xamarin.Forms library as foundation. From there I ported the code in chunks and made sure my tests were running after each chunk was moved. For you, I would check what HTTP implementation your android project is using then any packages crashing the app in the environment you're running the UI Tests on. If all this doesn't work you may have no choice but to do what I did. Good luck!